# Choosing constructor of class object field

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I have a class called Foo that has another class called Bar as a field. Bar only has a constructor with arguments. How do I choose the constructor with arguments for Bar (without storing a Bar* instead of Bar, and calling new)?

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        Bar bar;
};
```

Bar.h

```
class Bar
{
    public:
        Bar(int arbitraryArg);
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo()
  : bar(bar(1))
{}
```

I want to do the above because I hear that it is generally not good to store pointers as fields unless absolutely necessary to avoid managing memory, so I want to avoid something like this:

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        Bar* bar;

    public:
        Foo();
}
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo()
  : bar(NULL)
{
    bar = new Bar(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close.

```
Foo::Foo()
  : bar(1)
{}
```

You'll also need to declare the constructor `Foo()` in the class `Foo`'s definition (and all of your class definitions need a `;` at the end).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it was first and it worked. This is also a pretty cool shorthand way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks almost good - but you need to call the constructor, not the argument or variable name.

Change to:

`:bar(Bar(1)) {`

Note the capital B.

Comment: This answer works too, and is what I originally thought I had to do. The other answer is shorter, but this one may be more clear for beginners (like me)